# Maven environment specific build

Tags: apache, maven

I have 3 types of files depending on the environement I'm working on :

- file-dev.conf
- file-int.conf
- file-prd.conf

I would like to create three zips with maven-assembly :

- project-dev.zip
- project-int.zip
- project-prd.zip

The difficult part is I want :

- in the project-dev.zip the file-dev.conf only but rename in file.conf
- in the project-int.zip the file-int.conf only but rename in file.conf
- in the project-prd.zip the file-prd.conf only but rename in file.conf

Do any of you have the same problem? Did you find a solution?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes this is possible. Read about the assembly plugin. This is too broad.

Comment: have you look into maven-assembly-plugin?